# Deploying from Visual Studio to Hololens 2 Emulator works fine, but I can't deploy to the device itself via USB

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

When I try to deploy my Unity project to my HoloLens 2, deployment fails with the following message: "DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]"

It looks like something is wrong in the project properties because the properties window is showing
[Windows 10 as target platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMndK.png). I've tried deploying using Release, Master, and Debug in all combinations with x64 and ARM 64. This is a Unity project which is being built with the following settings for Build Settings under Universal Windows Platform:

- Target Device: HoloLens
- Architecture: x64
- Build Type: D3D Project
- Build and Run on: USB Device
- Build configuration: Release

Thank you!

Comment: Is the lens in developer mode? Are you logged in on the lens? Try to do it remote vis the Wifi IP or via the device portal as an app package instead

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this! Yes, the lens is in developer mode. I unfortunately don't have a wifi connection that I can use with the lens, but I'll look into device portal... Another computer deploying the same project to the exact same device isn't having any problem doing it.

Comment: It is recommended to re-pair your HoloLens with PC by the following steps. Please unpair all devices in Setting from your HoloLens and restart your device. After the device starts, deploy your project to your device, you will be prompted for a PIN to pair your device again.

Comment: For anyone else experiencing the same issue, the problem ended up being that usb connectivity was not installed in my version of Visual Studio. To solve this, I opened the Visual Studio Installer, clicked modify on my version of Visual Studio and then added the USB Device Connectivity individual component.